# why is the render image not the same as camera image

Tags: rendering, animation, image

I made some cog-wheels that rotate when I run them in the timeline. But when I try to render the images, the images shows all the cogs and everything is att frame 1 (even if I'm trying to render another frame).
I have tried both with cycles and Evee (since I thought Evee would simply give me what's on the screen from the camera-view), but no difference.
I have done animations before and never had this problem.

Any help is appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: maybe you haven't created any keyframe for the camera at the frame where you currently are, but it is keyframed at frame 1, so it will render frame 1, not the one where your are?

Comment: When I play the animation everything works just fine. And if I look at the animation through the camera there are no problems. I did create some keyframes for cameramovement, and when played up it looks good. It is as soon as I want to render a frame that it stops working.

Comment: maybe share your file (try to simplify it as much as possible): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Now I know how to do that too, haha :) Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Properties panel > Output > Post Processing*, disable the *Sequencer* option, otherwise you'll render what you see in the *Video Sequencer.*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much :)

Comment: Still not working tho... I can render one image at a time, but when I try to render animation as PNG's, it fails.

Comment: it works fine here, maybe share your file again wit your last settings

Comment: Jeez, I feel like an idiot now. Thanks for your patience. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=q61Zq5g4" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/q61Zq5g4/)

Comment: it still works fine for me, I can't tell what's your problem  :((

Comment: Now it works. Not, haha. It works for the first 100 frames... lol